# Getting request parameters in a Struts Action when you don't know what they are called

Tags: java, servlets, struts2

I have a struts `ActionSupport` class that uses a `Map<String, String>` to create `<input>` elements in a `jsp` where the name of the input is the key of the map. The map contains parameters (not fields) for a domain object I'm manipulating. I know that if you have a request parameter called, ex. `username`, you could have a field in the class

```
private String username;
```

with a getter and setter and it would be populated for you. However, I can't know the name of the request parameters. Is there any way of injecting all remaining (those not mapped to fields) request parameters as a map (or other structure)?

The other solution I can think of is to use

```
ServletActionContext.getRequest();
```

get the request parameters, and compare them myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement the [`ParameterAware`](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/interceptor/ParameterAware.html) interface and have the parameters injected into your action as a `Map<String, String[]>`. However, It will give you all the request parameters, not only those it could populate directly in the action.

Comment: That's fine. Do you know why the Map is raw and not `Map<String, String>` or `Map<String, String[]>`?

Comment: According to the docs it's `Map<String, String[]>` as far as I can see. I have updated the answer with that detail.

Comment: Oh right, I missed that _Note that all parameter values for a given name will be returned, so the type of the objects in the map is java.lang.String[]._ Thanks!

Comment: I'm using an older version of struts...so I have to use raw map.

Comment: Ah, ok. That explains the confusion :)

Comment: @DaveNewton I've been telling other SO users to always go with the most recent version of frameworks, but I've finally fallen in the situation where it is not currently possible/feasible.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I get that, but IIRC it doesn't have any of the security patches, specifically OGNL-related. I might be remembering wrongly, though.

Comment: @DaveNewton My username and password are root/root, good luck :) It's running in an internal network with a random ip and very specific context path.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis That's not the point; unless you don't care if a user inadvertently, or on purpose, causes the JVM itself to shut down or changes how S2 works, there are specific, non-trivial, holes. For apps that nobody cares about or uses, obviously it's not an issue.

Comment: @DaveNewton Then I'm missing something, because I don't see any huge issues. Do you have an example (even OGNL) that can cause trouble.

Comment: @DaveNewton Oh shit yeah: http://www.h-online.com/open/news/item/Critical-hole-in-Apache-Struts-2-closed-1419498.html, but this is like developer injection, which you'd have to have someone really hate you to do. And they could do much worse than that, regardless of struts.